# Access VBA: a record is added when a form with a bound table is closed

Tags: vba, list, ms-access

I am stuck with this problem and I have no idea what is going on. A form has a bound listbox, when an item on the list is selected, a user can delete that item from a related table by clicking a delete button. That part is simple, and it works. The problem is that every time the form is closed after a delete action, it adds a new record with the ID (Column 0) of the deleted record in the description field (Column 1) and a proper incremental ID in the ID field (Column 0). To make things worse, an unbound list would not allow item selection.

Here's a very simple delete code:

```
aSQL = "DELETE * FROM Category WHERE Cat_ID = " & Me.Update_Category_lstAllCats.Column(0)
DoCmd.RunSQL aSQL
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are selecting from a BOUND listbox, you will either edit an existing record or create a new record. Record edit is committed to table when form closes. This should be expected behavior. Item certainly can be selected from UNBOUND listbox so something is wrong with your design. Why allow user to delete category?

Comment: Where does this delete query fit into your problem?

Comment: June7, thank you for confirming that an UNBOUND listbox shouldn't preclude a selection. I thought I was loosing it... As to the BOUND box, I was expecting it to commit a deletion of a record, not to add a record. The category is not a data category. This is a separate table for categories of items that users can identify and self-select into.
ashleedawg - the deletion happens when user clicks a delete button (with the quoted code OnClick) after selecting an item from a list on a form. It all works great until the form closes. Then a record is added to a table as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is to define a row source in the Form_Load() sub like this:

```
Me.Update_Category_lstAllCats.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY Cat_Name;"
```

and to exclude any reference to a row source in the list properties. Then all other pieces fall into place.